# Триггеры для DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

Как изменить Background у StackPanel:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MainListBox">
        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Opacity="100"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="570" MinWidth="570" MinHeight="100" MaxWidth="570" MaxHeight="100" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" CanVerticallyScroll="True" Background="#FF008BFF">
            <Image Opacity="1" Height="90" Width="90" Source="{Binding Path=icon}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Width="370" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text="{Binding Path=title}" Foreground="White" SelectionOpacity="1" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" SelectionBrush="{x:Null}" Padding="0,0,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Cursor="Arrow" Background="Transparent" IsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="False" AllowDrop="False" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontSize="16"/>

        </StackPanel>

    </DataTemplate>
```

при наведении мышки например? с ControlTemplate получается, а тут нет... везде написаны пути вроде

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsFocused}"...
```

но я не понимаю как и где все это обрабатывается)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTrigger вообще не из этой оперы, это триггер на привязку (Binding).

Вот, например, триггер на IsMouseOver.

```
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Style>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" MinWidth="100" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: не работает) как были раньше настройки у StackPanel так и остались

П.С. извиняюсь, не отключил старые настройки(

Comment: Если Вы попытались прикрутить пример к своему, то он и не будет работать, так как Вы свойство Background задали при создании StackPanel. Стили в этом случае не применяются.

Обратите внимание, что у меня в примере свойство в обоих случаях задаётся через Setter в стиле.